# How to create list in Maya using python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

**Expected Output**
[image]

I want to create a UI in Maya 2014 which contains Layers and Camera given in the image .I don't know what widget to use for this.I tried to create and my code is given below.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

window = cmds.window( title="Render", iconName='BTD',widthHeight=
(400,300),titleBar=True,minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )

inner_child5 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1,rowSpacing = 
(1,5),columnOffset =(1,'left',10))

RL = cmds.text("Render Layers",width=200, 
height=50,font="boldLabelFont",align='left')

inner_child_5 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2,columnOffset =
(1,'left',10),rowOffset = (1,"bottom",30))

Layers = cmds.text("Layers",width=100, 
height=10,font="boldLabelFont",align='left')

camera = cmds.text("Camera",width=200, 
height=10,font="boldLabelFont",align='left')

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

Please tell me how to get that output and what widget to use ?

**Note:**

> I want to know that how to create the red lined part given in the image

Answer (score 1):

You might want a textScrollList widget ! (Using two of them side by side).

I can share with you the maya ui cheat sheet from Matt Murrey :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TQxp8BzPdLSW5zaWwxZkUta3M/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thanks but i want to select multiple layer and i can't select using textScrollList

Comment: In textScrollList, you have a flag allowMultiSelection